# Prevent chrome.notifications API from hiding my notification after a few seconds

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing around 1-2 notifications a day and it's important the user doesn't miss it.  Is there a way of removing the auto close and only allowing the user to manually close the notification?

I don's see any option for this in the Notification Options:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#type-NotificationOptions

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer below.

Comment: Did you try my solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: i switched to webkit notification, seemed easier.

Answer (score 21):

Notification now has (since Chrome 50) a [`requireInteraction` property](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#property-NotificationOptions-requireInteraction) to force the notification to stay on screen:

```js
var notification = new Notification("TITLE", {
          icon: 'assets/res/icon.png',
          body: "MESSAGE",
          requireInteraction: true     
});
```

In `onclick` you have to close the notification:

```js
notification.onclick = function()
{
    this.close();
}
```

Comment: The requireInteraction:true advice is correct but you do not have to manually close the notification in an onclick handler. The notifications all have a Close button that works out of the box.

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE (2016-05-24):**

[Xan commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326926/prevent-chrome-notifications-api-from-hiding-my-notification-after-a-few-seconds/20327118?noredirect=1#comment-62336235):

> Fun fact: all this arcane hacking is no longer needed; see the new `requireInteraction` flag

It is availalbe since Chrome 50. [More info](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#property-NotificationOptions-requireInteraction).

---

<sub>Thanks to root's comment, this answer is revised to account for the fact that the `onClosed` event is not fired when the notification disappears (into the notigications area) after a few seconds. This is still kind of a *hacky* solution.</sub>

---

#### Background

You can take advantage of the fact that a notification's life-cycle ends with one of the following events:

- **[`onClosed`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#event-onClosed)**: When the user clicks on the small 'x' in the top-right corner.
- **[`onClicked`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#event-onClicked)**: When the user clicks on the message body (not the 'x', not some button).
- **[`onButtonClicked`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#event-onButtonClicked)**: When the user clicks on one of the buttons (if any).

#### The solution

The proposed solution consists of the following steps:

1. Register listeners for all the events mentioned above.
2. Register a timeout after a few seconds (e.g. 30) -after the notification is hidden- that will **[delete](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#method-clear)** and re-**[create](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#method-create)** the notification (so it effectively stays visible on the screen.
3. If any of the listeners set on step 1 fires, it means the user interracted with the notification, so cancel the timeout (you don't need to re-create the notification).

Writing about it is simple, coding takes some more effort :)
Here is the sample code I used to achieve what is described above:

**In *manifest.json*:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        // We need this for the `Timeout` - see notes below
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "img/icon19.png",
            "38": "img/icon38.png"
        },
    },

    "permissions": ["notifications"]
}
```

**In *background.js*:**

```
var pendingNotifications = {};

/* For demonstration purposes, the notification creation
 * is attached to the browser-action's `onClicked` event.
 * Change according to your needs. */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    var dateStr = new Date().toUTCString();
    var details = {
        type:    "basic",
        iconUrl: "/img/notifIcon.png",
        title:   "REMINDER",
        message: dateStr + "\n\n"
                 + "There is one very important matter to attend to !\n"
                 + "Deal with it now ?",
        contextMessage: "Very important stuff...",
        buttons: [
            { title: "Yes" }, 
            { title: "No"  }
        ]
    };
    var listeners = {
        onButtonClicked: function(btnIdx) {
            if (btnIdx === 0) {
                console.log(dateStr + ' - Clicked: "yes"');
            } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
                console.log(dateStr + ' - Clicked: "no"');
            }
        },
        onClicked: function() {
            console.log(dateStr + ' - Clicked: "message-body"');
        },
        onClosed: function(byUser) {
            console.log(dateStr + ' - Closed: '
                        + (byUser ? 'by user' : 'automagically (!?)'));
        }
    };

    /* Create the notification */
    createNotification(details, listeners);
});

/* Create a notification and store references
 * of its "re-spawn" timer and event-listeners */
function createNotification(details, listeners, notifId) {
    (notifId !== undefined) || (notifId = "");
    chrome.notifications.create(notifId, details, function(id) {
        console.log('Created notification "' + id + '" !');
        if (pendingNotifications[id] !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(pendingNotifications[id].timer);
        }

        pendingNotifications[id] = {
            listeners: listeners,
            timer: setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('Re-spawning notification "' + id + '"...');
                destroyNotification(id, function(wasCleared) {
                    if (wasCleared) {
                        createNotification(details, listeners, id);
                    }
                });
            }, 10000)
        };
    });
}

/* Completely remove a notification, cancelling its "re-spawn" timer (if any)
 * Optionally, supply it with a callback to execute upon successful removal */
function destroyNotification(notifId, callback) {

    /* Cancel the "re-spawn" timer (if any) */
    if (pendingNotifications[notifId] !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(pendingNotifications[notifId].timer);
        delete(pendingNotifications[notifId]);
    }

    /* Remove the notification itself */
    chrome.notifications.clear(notifId, function(wasCleared) {
        console.log('Destroyed notification "' + notifId + '" !');

        /* Execute the callback (if any) */
        callback && callback(wasCleared);
    });
}

/* Respond to the user's clicking one of the buttons */
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
    if (pendingNotifications[notifId] !== undefined) {
        var handler = pendingNotifications[notifId].listeners.onButtonClicked;
        destroyNotification(notifId, handler(btnIdx));
    }
});

/* Respond to the user's clicking on the notification message-body */
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notifId) {
    if (pendingNotifications[notifId] !== undefined) {
        var handler = pendingNotifications[notifId].listeners.onClicked;
        destroyNotification(notifId, handler());
    }
});

/* Respond to the user's clicking on the small 'x' in the top right corner */
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function(notifId, byUser) {
    if (pendingNotifications[notifId] !== undefined) {
        var handler = pendingNotifications[notifId].listeners.onClosed;
        destroyNotification(notifId, handler(byUser));
    }
});
```

---

<sub>Final notes:</sub>

- <sub>If your notifications are extremely important, you should implement a "recovery" mechanism, for case such as browser os OS crashes or abrupt termination. E.g. relying on a more persistent storage (**[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)**, **[`chrome.storage` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)** etc), resuming pending notifications on extension/browser start-up etc.</sub>
- <sub>It might be a good idea to put a limit on the total number of pending notifications, for "user-friendliness" reasons. If your pending notifications exceed, say, 3 at any given moment, you could replace them with one that informs there are pending notifications and direct the user to a page where you list all of them. (The code will be considerably more complex, but hey anything for the user, right ? ;)</sub>
- <sub>Instead of trying to keep the notifications visible on screen until the user decides to deal with them, it could be better using a **[Badge](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#badge)** (wich can have a color and a small text - indicating the number of pending notifications.</sub>
- <sub>I haven't looked into it, but it might be possible (in which case it is advisable as well) to replace the `Timeout`'s with the **[`chrome.alarms` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html)** and then convert the background-page to non-persistent (a.k.a. **[event-page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**) which will make it more resource-friendly.</sub>

Comment: this event doesn't seem to be fired when notification goes away from the screen after 5 seconds. I guess it is not counted as "closed" as you can still see it IF you click on sys tray icon

Comment: @root: You were write :/ I revised my answer. Thx for the heads-up.

Comment: nice one. how do you match respawn timeout with the chrome hide timeout to give impression it's a persistent notification rather than "keeps popping up"?

Comment: You could made the refresh timeout sufficiently short (e.g. 5 secs), but I believe it is unnecessary overhead. The user is either away (so it doesn't matter how often we re-spawn the notification until (s)he comes back) or (s)he is there but deliberately chooses to ignore our notification (so shoosing a very short refresh interval would be rather annoying). In would suggest something between 30 secs and 5 mins (based on how "urgent" the notification is).

Comment: [We](https://idorecall.com)'re using the alarms technique to trigger periodic notifications and it works well. chrome.alarms.create and `chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener`.

Comment: Fun fact: all this arcane hacking is no longer needed; see the new `requireInteraction` flag.

Answer (score 4):

**This answer is obsolete**; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36553583/934239) for an up to date solution involving `requireInteraction` flag (Chrome 50+).

---

There is a slightly better (but again, hacky) solution.

When you call `update` on a notification that changes its priority, and the priority is 0 or above, the notification will be re-shown and the timer for hiding it reset.

So, you can show a notification with a high priority, (say, 2) and then repeat this on an interval shorter than time to hide the notification:

```
chrome.notifications.update(id, {priority : 1}, function(wasUpdated) {
  if(wasUpdated) {
    chrome.notifications.update(id, {priority : 2}, function() {});
  } else {
    // Notification was fully closed; either stop updating or create a new one
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

## UPDATE answar: after Chrome 50, please add new attribute: [requireInteraction: true]!

don't use `chrome.notifications.create`

try to use `var notification= new Notification("New mail from John Doe", { tag: 'msg1', requireInteraction: true});`
will not to close.

if want to close=> `notification.close();`

ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/requireInteraction

Comment: Just to improve the answer you might want to add some explanation why not to use it.

Comment: on Google Chrome v48, the notification closes after few seconds. Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

webkit notifications seem to be more persistent on the screen, althouth they have the opposite problem - how to hide them to sys tray.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications.html

Comment: I don't think this is true anymore.