# Is it possible to have a *sticky* Chrome notification (for extensions)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need a chrome extension notification that does not fade away after 5 seconds.

Is it possible to keep it visible until user interaction?

Comment: This was asked before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326926/prevent-chrome-notifications-api-from-hiding-my-notification-after-a-few-seconds).

Comment: I added a new answer to that question, you might want to check it out.