# How to set a closing time for notification extension chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension with chrome.notifications would like to set a time for closing the notification, how can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome automatically *hides* the notification. How long it stays on screen depends on the `priority` attribute. Note that everywhere except Chrome OS the hidden notification is effectively closed, as the [Notification Center was removed](https://blog.chromium.org/2015/10/streamlining-notifications-on-desktop.html).

It's possible to keep the notification shown, <del>but you'll have to resort to [dirty tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26449044/934239). If you don't want to do it the hard way, consider using [Web Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications) instead - they will not be hidden.</del>

**Update:** Both `chrome.notifications` and Web Notifications APIs now implement a boolean flag `requireInteraction` that defines whether Chrome will fade the notification away automatically or not.

You can still manually *close* (i.e., remove completely) the notification by calling `chrome.notifications.clear()` with the notification ID.

To schedule something, you can either use DOM intervals, or [`chrome.alarms` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms).

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this in my project

```
var opt = {type, title, message, etc....}

chrome.notifications.create("", opt, function(id) {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.clear(id);}, 2000);
});
```

notification is closed after 2 sec (2000 ms)

Comment: Works well for short times, but needs additional magic to keep displayed for longer times.

Comment: yea, I presumed that he want's short(er) time just to flash notification and not to bother users with closing it (I need that behavior), but for longer than default, this won't work